# Is is possible to detect an iphone's/ Android's handset language?

Tags: html, localization

Been searching for this for a while and can't see a clear answer.

--> Is there a way to detect the handset language for iphone/ android handsets from within mobile web.

We want to try and improve the way we serve our pages for languages other than english.

Comment: Other than the normal HTTP mechanism for client language selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript `window.navigator.language` usually works except for earlier versions of Android which have it hardcoded to `en`.

For older Androids I suggest pulling the language parameter out of the UserAgent string (yes sniffing!), e.g.

```
if (navigator && navigator.userAgent && (androidLang = navigator.userAgent.match(/android.*\W(\w\w)-(\w\w)\W/i))) {
   lang = androidLang[1];
}
```

Here, lang might also contain the country code (e.g. 'en-IE') so you might have to remove that also:

```
if (lang.indexOf('-') != -1) lang = lang.substring(0, lang.indexOf('-'));
```

This is what I've used in a recent app and it works fine.